# UIScrollview's elements are not responsive

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` , inside that there's another `UIView`- `InsideView` . In the `InsideView` I have kept `TextViews` , `tableview` and `Button` . But nothing is responding to touch event . As I try to scroll the `tableview` , `mainView` scrolls not the `tableview`. Likewise nothing is responding to touch event else `UIScrollView`.

I have checked that `UserInteraction` is enabled and also `clipsToBounds`yes .

How to make the `UIElements`  responsive ?

Comment: Have you set the `UIScrollView` content size correctly?

Comment: Yes , I have set the `content size` to (375 , 1000) in `Identity Inspector `'s user defined runtime attributes .

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to keep uitableview inside a uiscrollview since table view itself has its own scrollview and which might conflict with yours

Comment: Yes , I come to know afterword ,but I was heaving specific requirement . But   lately I managed it with removing `InsideView` and disabling scrolling of tableview in `viewDidLayotSubViews` .